# opening folder in python

Tags: python, client, directory

I have a Client_server code in python, but I cant run Client part of it, I debug it but still it has error, I think that's error exist because the program cant open the folder (files) because that's address isn't correct, please help me to correct it!

```
import socket
import sys
host = 'localhost'
port = 5000
file_name = sys.argv[0]
message = open(file_name+'/files/').read()
print ('Request\n', repr(message))
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((str(host), int(port)))
s.sendall(message)
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print ('Response\n', repr(data))
```

I tried to correct my code, my new code is:

```
import socket
import sys
import os
host = 'localhost'
port = 5000
file_name = sys.argv[0]
message = open(os.path.dirname(file_name)+'/files/').read()
print ('Request\n', repr(message))
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((str(host), int(port)))
s.sendall(message)
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print ('Response\n', repr(data))
```

and

C:\Python33\python.exe C:/Users/M.H/Desktop/Client/Client.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/M.H/Desktop/Client/Client.py", line 7, in 
    message = open(os.path.dirname(file_name)+'/files/').read()
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/M.H/Desktop/Client/files/'

now I do what??? please help me!!!!

Comment: Perhaps you meant `open(os.path.dirname(file_name) + '/files/')`. Also you should close the files you open.

Comment: So, where's the error? You are likely getting an exception at `message = open(file_name+'/files/').read()` because you can't have file names that end in slashes. Everything likely went bad at `file_name = sys.argv[0]`. If you want the directory your script is in, you need to do `os.path.dirname`. Try some prints and look at the line with the exception.

Comment: I tried to correct my code, my new code is: import socket
import sys
import os
host = 'localhost'
port = 5000
file_name = sys.argv[0]
message = open(os.path.dirname(file_name)+'/files/').read()
print ('Request\n', repr(message))
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((str(host), int(port)))
s.sendall(message)
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print ('Response\n', repr(data))

Comment: @tdelaney oops, I added dir name but missed file itself :)

Comment: You still aren't passing a valid file name. Compare the name you tried to open with the name you want to open. What's different?

Comment: nothing... those are same

Comment: I copied my error below of my code... (PermissionError) enybody cant help me???!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're trying to read a *directory*.

The following line is the problem:

```
message = open(os.path.dirname(file_name)+'/files/').read()
```

You're trying to open `os.path.dirname(file_name)+'/files/'`, which would translate to `'C:/Users/M.H/Desktop/Client/files/'` which is a *folder*. You can't open folders for reading and that's the `Permission denied` error. If you want to open a file that is inside a "files" directory at the same level as you Client.py file, then you should add the name of the file that you want to read. For example, if you have a message.txt file inside that folder, you should do

```
message = open(os.path.dirname(file_name)+'/files/message.txt').read()
```

The code would like like this:

```
import socket
import sys
import os
host = 'localhost'
port = 5000
file_name = sys.argv[0]
# You need to pass the full path to the file instead of the folder to the open function
message = open(os.path.dirname(file_name)+'/files/message.txt').read()
print ('Request\n', repr(message))
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((str(host), int(port)))
s.sendall(message)
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print ('Response\n', repr(data))
```

Comment: the files folder contains GET PUT PATCH DELETE ,... file. do you think this code handle my purpose?

Comment: In that case, just do: `message = open(os.path.dirname(file_name)+'/files/GET').read()`